# Use API to write to json file

Tags: python

I am facing this problem while I try to loop `tweet_id` using the API and write it to `tweet_json.txt`, the output for all data is `Failed` which I know is wrong

Before it was working good but when I try to Run all the code again it starts to show failed

```
for tweet_id in df['tweet_id']:
    try:
        tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id, tweet_mode = 'extended')
        with open('tweet_json.txt', 'a+') as file:
            json.dump(tweet._json, file)
            file.write('\n')
        print (tweet_id, 'success')
    except:
        print (tweet_id, 'Failed')
```

Comment: use `except Exception as e: print(e)` to see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `except` is swallowing whatever exception is causing your code to die. Until you comment out the `except` or make it more specific you won't know if your problem is the Twitter API or file I/O or something else. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A quick step forward would be to adjust your exception handler so that it writes the exception. I like to use the format_exc function to get my stack traces so i can write it with a logger, or however i want to handle it.

```
from traceback import format_exc


try:
    a = "" + 1
except Exception as ex:
    print("Exception encountered! \n %s " % format_exc())
```